# Docker multi-stage builds stuck between layers when using Docker-in-Docker with Jenkins and Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

Big title, I know, but it is a very specific issue.

I'm creating a new Jenkins cluster, and trying to use Docker-in-Docker containers to build images, differently from the current Jenkins cluster that uses that ugly-as-hell `/var/run/docker.sock`. The context of the things being built is a monorepo with some `Dockerfile`s, with builds running in parallel.

The problem is, when building huge layers (for example, after an `yarn install` that downloads half of the internet), the step hangs in that `Done in XX.XXs` and does not goes to the next step, whatever it is.

Sometimes the build passes successfully (generally when I change something in the cluster), but the next ones hangs forever. When it passes, I can build 8 nodejs images in ~28min, but the next ones times out after 60min.

Here follows some code to show how I'm doing this. All the other images have the same template than the provided one.

- Jenkins pod template:

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "Pod"
  metadata:
    labels:
      name: "jnlp"
      jenkins/jenkins-jenkins-agent: "true"
  spec:
    containers:
    - env:
      - name: "DOCKER_HOST"
        value: "tcp://localhost:2375"
      image: "12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/kubernetes-agent:2.0" # internal image
      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
      name: "jnlp"
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "1000m"
          memory: "1Gi"
        requests:
          cpu: "500m"
          memory: "500Mi"
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/home/jenkins"
        name: "workspace-volume"
        readOnly: false
      workingDir: "/home/jenkins"
    - args:
      - "--tls=false"
      env:
      - name: "DOCKER_BUILDKIT"
        value: "1"
      - name: "DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR"
        value: ""
      - name: "DOCKER_DRIVER"
        value: "overlay2"
      image: "docker:20.10.12-dind-alpine3.15"
      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
      name: "docker"
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "4Gi"
          cpu: "2"
        requests:
          memory: "1Gi"
          cpu: "500m"
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/var/lib/docker"
        name: "docker"
        readOnly: false
      - mountPath: "/home/jenkins"
        name: "workspace-volume"
        readOnly: false
      workingDir: "/home/jenkins"
    nodeSelector:
      spot: "true"
    restartPolicy: "Never"
    volumes:
    - emptyDir:
        medium: ""
      name: "docker"
    - emptyDir:
        medium: ""
      name: "workspace-volume"
  ```
- Dockerfile

  ```
  # We don't use alpine image due to dependency issues
  FROM node:12.14.1-stretch-slim as base

  RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
      apt-utils build-essential bzip2 ca-certificates cron curl g++ git libfontconfig make python \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    && rm -f /var/log/alternatives.log /var/log/apt/* \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm /var/cache/debconf/*-old

  ENV NODE_ENV development

  # Put here, to optimize caching
  EXPOSE 8043

  WORKDIR /opt/app
  RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app

  USER node

  COPY --chown=node:node package.json yarn.lock .yarnclean /opt/app/
  COPY 100-wkhtmltoimage-special.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/

  RUN yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g && \
      yarn --frozen-lockfile && \
      yarn autoclean --force && \
      yarn cache clean

  FROM base as dev

  # --debug and inspect port
  EXPOSE 5858 9229
  COPY --chown=node:node . /opt/app
  RUN npx gulp build && sh ./app-ssl

  FROM base as prod

  COPY --from=dev /opt/app /opt/app

  # Like `npm prune --production`
  RUN yarn --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline

  CMD ["yarn", "start"]
  ```
- The command:

  ```sh
  docker build \
    --network host --force-rm \
    --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 \
    --cache-from 12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/name-of-my-image:latest \
    --cache-from 12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/name-of-my-image:latest-dev \
    --cache-from 12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/name-of-my-image:${VERSION} \
    --cache-from 12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/name-of-my-image:${VERSION}-dev \
    --tag 12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/name-of-my-image:${VERSION}-dev \
    --tag 12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/name-of-my-image:latest-dev \
    --target dev .
  ```
- The end of the log:

  ```
  ...
  [2022-01-18T19:37:19.928Z] [4/5] Building fresh packages...
  [2022-01-18T19:37:19.928Z] [5/5] Cleaning modules...
  [2022-01-18T19:37:34.774Z] Done in 486.04s.
  [2022-01-18T19:37:34.774Z] yarn autoclean v1.21.1
  [2022-01-18T19:37:34.774Z] [1/1] Cleaning modules...
  [2022-01-18T19:37:46.952Z] info Removed 0 files
  [2022-01-18T19:37:46.952Z] info Saved 0 MB.
  [2022-01-18T19:37:46.952Z] Done in 12.85s.
  [2022-01-18T19:37:46.952Z] yarn cache v1.21.1
  [2022-01-18T19:38:13.453Z] success Cleared cache.
  [2022-01-18T19:38:13.453Z] Done in 24.21s.
  [2022-01-18T20:28:51.170Z] make: *** [Makefile:21: build-dev] Terminated <=== Pipeline reaches timeout! Look how long it hangs from the previous line.
  script returned exit code 2
  ```

If anyone needs any more information, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using? Do you have any issues running Kubernetes pods - are they creating properly, are they in running state, finishing properly?

Comment: Using K8s 1.21 (EKS). The Pods run just fine, this Kubernetes cluster only has some managing apps (cluster-autoscaler, prometheus, cert-manager, etc.) and Jenkins. All agent pods are finishing properly as well. I'm testing right now if it works without parallelism to see if this is the issue.

Comment: It works without parralel jobs =/
So I'll use this way while I figure out why the parallel jobs don't work. So if anyone can help, please let me know.